# List users in nested, cross-forest AD groups using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I've tried to search for something that matches my case, but I can't find any concrete matches.

I'm trying to do an audit for users with access to certain groups in AD. Now, most of these would be members of nested groups some levels down, until finally the last group would be a cross-forest group containing just one user member in another domain.

So, say I want to check users that in some way have access through the security group XXapplication-access-group1. in the domain **vs.old.domain**.

This security group would in turn have it's own member groups, for example:
XXworkplace-access-group2. Members if this group, in turn, would be a cross-forest global group in the domain **in.new.domain** with a single user-object as member.

These are the objects that I'm interested in listing. I can get members that are directly memberOf this group, but I can't get this part to work.

I have been through several iterations now, but I'll include my latest one. I am unsure whether or not this would work or if I'll just mess things up by using the "where", but here goes;

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$GroupName = "XXapplication-access-group1"
$ExportFile = "\\server\script\$GroupName members.csv"


Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName -Recursive | Where {$_.objectClass -eq "user"}| Export-Csv $ExportFile
```

The issue here is twofold. I can run this without recursive, but that will obviously not get me the members in groups one level down. If I run with the recursive flag the script won't return anything other than an error. The error doesn't even make sense since I should be able to browse through all these groups.

The error is;

```
Get-ADGroupMember : The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated
At xxx
+ Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName -Recursive | Where {$_.objectClass -eq " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (XXapplication-access-group1:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome here